# Hook a custom function for label's click event

Tags: c#

How do I hook a custom function, so that on label click, the same function would run and pass the parameters?

```
List<int> _list1 = new List<int>(); //1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    foreach (var item in _list1)
    {
        Label lb = new Label { Text = item.ToString() };
    lb.Click += //custom function and pass the parameter item

    }

private void CustomFunctionOnClick(int s)
{
textBox1.Text = s.ToString();
}
```

-> I can't hook delegates with the click event of label. 
-> For the other way round, I could have a CustomEventArgs class that would pass the data to the event `(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)`, and I could do run same code in the event.
But the click event delegate does not define CustomEventArgs as the parameter for the event?

Then, how is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<int> _list1 = new List<int>(); //1, 2, 3, 4, 5

foreach (var item in _list1)
{
    // take copy of loop variable to avoid closing over the loop variable
    int i = item; 
    Label lb = new Label { Text = item.ToString() };
    lb.Click += (x,y) => CustomFunction(i);
}

void CustomFunction(int item)
{
}
```

Comment: Just curious to know how would I have doen this without lambda function? :-/

Comment: lb.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) { CustomFunction(i); };

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
List<int> _list1 = new List<int>(); //1, 2, 3, 4, 5

foreach (var item in _list1)
{
    Label lb = new Label { Text = item.ToString() };
    lb.Tag = item;
    lb.Click += CustomFunctionOnClick;
}

private void CustomFunctionOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label l = (Label)sender;
    int item = l.Tag;
}
```